# PHP RegExp: Validate date (or "RegExp must match exactly")

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to match a date-format in PHP using a regular expression. To keep it simple, it can be extended later anyway, the regex should also match `2012-30-60` (which is not a valid date).

My expression is the following: `"/\s*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*/i"`. Using `preg_match` works fine, but it also matches dates that have preceding and appending characters, like `"Hello 2012-09-01 Goodbye."`

How can I make the regex to match **only** when the expression matches **the whole string**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/i"
```

^ means "begin of string/line"

$ means "end of string/line"

Comment: Ahh right, I saw that somewhere, just didn't remember it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ^ and $ at beginning and end of your regexp

```
"/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/i"
```